# How to iterate over a batch DF parallely in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using pyspark version 3.1.1-amzn-0 in an EMR where I am iterating over a batch DF and for each record I am filtering some data from a delta DF and then producing the results in a kafka topic, but this seems to be running sequentially and I want to process multiple records in parallel for better performance, so how can I do this.

Below I have attached my approach,

```
# Reading the deltaTable
deltaDf = spark.read \
        .format("delta") \
        .load("s3://deltaLake/")

def processEachMicroBatch(batchDF, epochId):
    
    kafka_df_rows = batchDF.collect()

    for index, row in enumerate(kafka_df_rows):

        anon_id = row['anon_id']
        pro_id = row['pro_id']
        prof_id = row['prof_id']
        key = anon_id[0:3]

        filteredDF = deltaDf.filter((deltaDf.pro_id == pro_id) & (deltaDf.key == key) & (deltaDf.anon_id == anon_id) & (deltaDf.prof_id == prof_id))

        if filteredDF.rdd.isEmpty():
            exec_status_data = [(pro_id, anon_id, prof_id)]
            exec_status_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=exec_status_data, schema=schema)
            exec_status_df = exec_status_df.withColumn("dataNotFound", lit(True))
            produceDFMessagesInKafka(exec_status_df, 'kafkaTopic')
        else:
            produceDFMessagesInKafka(filteredDF, 'kafkaTopic')
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you're doing too much lifting that Spark can handle, killing the parallelization that Spark can offer out of the box.

I would advise the following approach instead:

```
# use withColumn() to handle "key = anon_id[0:3]"

def filter_delta_with_batch(delta_df, batch_df):
    filtered_df = delta_df.join(
        batch_df,
        (delta_df.pro_id == batch_df.pro_id) & (delta_df.key == batch_df.key) & (delta_df.anon_id == batch_df.anon_id) & (delta_df.prof_id == batch_df.prof_id),
        how='leftsemi',
    )
    return filtered_df

# process filtered_df with kafka
```

You might be worried that a join would be highly inefficient here but leftsemi and leftanti are powerful Spark joins for filtering data. Of course it might depends on data repartition / shuffle induced.